# What is substitute of keyboard for iphone?

Tags: iphone, uikeyboard

I am making an application in which i have use a keyboard for input in text field. Now my client requirement is that he need a substitute of keyboard input for text field. Basically i have need increment and decrement value of text field. SO i need some other function which is used for increment and decrement value of text field. For that i have use keyboard and now i require any other function like increment and decrement operator or tap to increment and decrement text or any thing else. What i used for that purpose?

Thanks in advances...

Comment: I respect tools available by default. But i need so i ask that question.

Comment: How about using UIStepper provided in iOS 5?

Comment: @DShah no i don't have ios 5.

Comment: then as hotpaw2 says... you can achieve a UIStepper control in same way by putting up/down button and have your logic on buttons...

Answer (score 2):

Put a pair of up/down buttons next to the text field.  UIButtons will still work when the keyboard is visible.  You can also hide these buttons when they aren't needed.